# Cannot install virtualbox 5.1 on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: virtualbox, 17.04

I have downloaded virtualbox 5.1 from the virtualbox website but I can't install it. When I open the .deb file with ubuntu software and I click on Install, it doesn't do nothing. I also tried from the command line, but it says that there's an [error on the dependencies.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oADuc.png) I also tried by adding the repository and then download the package, but it says that [it's not available.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VZyF.png)

Help me, please!

Thanks.

Comment: What did you download and from where? What error messages? Please [edit] and post the error message in its entirety.

Comment: Virtualbox 5.1 is in the current set of packages for Ubuntu show you shouldn't normally need to download the .deb file manually. Just use the software package manager to install it and it will automatically take care of any dependencies.

Comment: Execute the process from the official virtualbox site and you should have no problems. https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Comment: Are you sure you actually added the PPA?

Comment: @ScottStensland the question is three years old.

Answer (score 1):

1. Verify you downloaded the correct package i386/amd64 from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads
2. `sudo dpkg -i virtualbox*.deb`
   It throws dependencies error
3. `sudo apt-get -f install`
4. run `sudo dpkg -i virtualbox*.deb` again.

You can easily install from ppa
`sudo apt-get install virtualbox`

Comment: I tried it but doesn't work. :(

Comment: can you update ur question with the os version? 32/64 and which error have you got?
run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

Try running this

```
$ echo deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list
$ wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.1
```

After it finishes installing run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

just to make sure you got the latest version